# Convert html to plain text in VBA

Tags: html, parsing, vba, html-parsing

I have an Excel sheet with cells containing html. How can I batch convert them to plaintext? At the moment there are so many useless tags and styles. I want to write it from scratch but it will be far easier if I can get the plain text out.

I can write a script to convert html to plain text in PHP so if you can't think of a solution in VBA then maybe you can sugest how I might pass the cells data to a website and retrieve the data back.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set a reference to "Microsoft HTML object library".

```
Function HtmlToText(sHTML) As String
  Dim oDoc As HTMLDocument
  Set oDoc = New HTMLDocument
  oDoc.body.innerHTML = sHTML
  HtmlToText = oDoc.body.innerText
End Function
```

Tim

Comment: This works well, but be aware that white space is collapsed. For example `<div>this[space][space][space]is</div><div>a[space]test</div>` comes out as `this[space]isa[space]test`. (sorry about the formatting; the extra spaces aren't coming out when I just type them.)

Comment: Collapsing whitespace would be "expected behaviour" here I think (unless the element text has been styled using css to preserve whitespace)

Answer (score 5):

A very simple way to extract text is to scan the HTML character by character, and accumulate characters outside of angle brackets into a new string.

```
Function StripTags(ByVal html As String) As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim accumulating As Boolean
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim c As String

    text = ""
    accumulating = True

    n = 1
    Do While n <= Len(html)

        c = Mid(html, n, 1)
        If c = "<" Then
            accumulating = False
        ElseIf c = ">" Then
            accumulating = True
        Else
            If accumulating Then
                text = text & c
            End If
        End If

        n = n + 1
    Loop

    StripTags = text
End Function
```

This can leave lots of extraneous whitespace, but it will help in removing the tags.

Comment: Be careful with this approach.  If the input text includes < or > characters for a reason other than tags it will get confused.

Answer (score 5):

Tim's solution was great, worked liked a charm.

I´d like to contribute: Use this code to add the "Microsoft HTML Object Library" in runtime:

```
Set ID = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
ID.AddFromGuid "{3050F1C5-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}", 2, 5
```

It worked on Windows XP and Windows 7.

Comment: Can you show an example how this can be used with Tim's code and `Option Explicit` ?

Comment: still working - windows 10.. thank you for this.

Answer (score 2):

Tim's answer is excellent. However, a minor adjustment can be added to avoid one foreseeable error response.

```
 Function HtmlToText(sHTML) As String
      Dim oDoc As HTMLDocument

      If IsNull(sHTML) Then
        HtmlToText = ""
        Exit Function
        End-If

      Set oDoc = New HTMLDocument
      oDoc.body.innerHTML = sHTML
      HtmlToText = oDoc.body.innerText
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation of Tim's and Gardoglee's solution that does not require setting a reference to "Microsoft HTML object library".  This method is known as *Late Binding* and will also work in vbscript.

```
Function HtmlToText(sHTML) As String

    Dim oDoc As Object ' As HTMLDocument

    If IsNull(sHTML) Then
        HtmlToText = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set oDoc = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")
    oDoc.body.innerHTML = sHTML
    HtmlToText = oDoc.body.innerText

End Function
```

Note that if you are using VBA in **Access** 2007 or greater, there is an [Application.PlainText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.plaintext) method built-in that does the same thing as the code above.

Comment: I love the `Application.PlainText()` function!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I managed to solve my problem as well. Thanks everybody/

In my case, I had this sort of input:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>

<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.</p>
```

And I did not want the result to be all jammed together without breaklines.

So I first splitted my input for every `<p>` tag into an array 'paragraphs', then for each element I used Tim's answer to get the text out of html (very sweet answer btw).

In addition I concatenated each cleaned 'paragraph' with this breakline character `Crh(10)` for VBA/Excel.

**The final code is:**

```
Public Function HtmlToText(ByVal sHTML As String) As String
    Dim oDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim result As String
    Dim paragraphs() As String

    If IsNull(sHTML) Then
      HtmlToText = ""
      Exit Function
    End If

    result = ""
    paragraphs = Split(sHTML, "<p>")

    For Each paragraph In paragraphs
        Set oDoc = New HTMLDocument
        oDoc.body.innerHTML = paragraph
        result = result & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & oDoc.body.innerText
    Next paragraph

    HtmlToText = result
End Function
```