# Sending multiple email using range with attachment in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is the first time I am trying from Excel to send email using VBA code.

Here is my structure of my Excel. Sometimes the email list will have 1 - 20 or only 1 also

```
A (col) B          C         D        E     F              G
Sl.No  First Name To Email  CC Email Subj   File to Send   Message
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendMail()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngBody As Range
Dim rngAttach As Range

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With ActiveSheet
Set rngTo = .Range("C2")
Set rngSubject = .Range("E2")
Set rngBody = .Range("G2")
Set rngAttach = .Range("F2")
End With

With objMail
    .To = rngTo.Value
    .Subject = rngSubject.Value
    .Body = rngBody.Value
    .Attachments.Add rngAttach.Value
    .Display

End With

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set rngTo = Nothing
Set rngSubject = Nothing
Set rngBody = Nothing
Set rngAttach = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is my code this was working perfectly fine but for single emails to send, but not for multiple email.

I am struggling here to find how to send for multiple email with attachment using the tested code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maybe Try this:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendMail()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngBody As Range
Dim rngAttach As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


For i = 2 To 21 ' Loop from 2 to 21


    With ActiveSheet
    Set rngTo = .Range("C" & i)
    Set rngSubject = .Range("E" & i)
    Set rngBody = .Range("G" & i)
    Set rngAttach = .Range("F" & i)
    End With

    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With objMail
        .To = rngTo.Value
        .Subject = rngSubject.Value
        .HTMLBody = "<B><U>" & rngBody.Value & ":</B></U>"
        .Attachments.Add rngAttach.Value
        .Display

    End With

    Set objMail = Nothing

Next

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set rngTo = Nothing
Set rngSubject = Nothing
Set rngBody = Nothing
Set rngAttach = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can loop through the Range to generate 20 emails.

---

**Update**

- Added `.HTMLBody` instead of `.Body` to make text Bold And Underlined
- You can use more HTML commands to make certain portions of the Text Bold and More.

Comment: thanks for your code you forgot to declare i that is where the problem it solved now

Comment: it was worked initially but suddenly now I am getting automation error can you please help on this

Comment: hi Mikku thanks for the prompt message i found how to solve that can you please let me know how to make my body content in rich test format

Comment: This Answer by Tim might help you @Mahadevan ... [Convert html to plain text in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5334547/5720144)

Comment: actually I am new to the vba can you please update your code with the plain text to Rich text (bold ,underline)

Comment: Sure.. Give me few minutes... But no More changes... if you another issue.. You should ask a new question :)

Comment: thanks but not this way i asked  this was changed all text in to bold and underline but my question was i was having one format i copied and paste in the cell the same format came but in the email the format change

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop for that. The below code will start with the second row and continue until it finds an empty row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendMail()
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim rngSubject As Range
    Dim rngBody As Range
    Dim rngAttach As Range

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim r As Long: For r = 2 To ActiveSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
        With ActiveSheet
            Set rngTo = .Range("C" & r)
            Set rngSubject = .Range("E" & r)
            Set rngBody = .Range("G" & r)
            Set rngAttach = .Range("F" & r)
        End With

        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
        With objMail
            .to = rngTo.Value
            .Subject = rngSubject.Value
            .Body = rngBody.Value
            .Attachments.Add rngAttach.Value
            .Display
            .Send ' If you want to send it without clicking
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Also note: `These Set x = Nothing` lines are superfluous, delete them because they just make the code less readable for humans. Regarding this issue you can also refer to this SO question: [Is there a need to set Objects to Nothing inside VBA Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517006/is-there-a-need-to-set-objects-to-nothing-inside-vba-functions)

**Update**

Sorry this line has to be inside the loop, I updated the code:

```
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I have query here 

Dim r As Long: For r = 2 To ActiveSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row what is R = 2

Comment: That is not a query, it is a loop. r will be equal to 2, then 3, then ... until an empty row is encountered. And for each value of r, an email will be sent. The code references r for example in this line: Set rngTo = .Range("C" & r), so at the first iteration it reads from C2, then from C3, etc.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement

Comment: actually I am getting different error if I am altering the r = 5 Automation error unspecified error 

In your code if i am entering 5 it was selecting 5 row but i want 1 - 5 rows 

Can you please help me here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197720/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-z32a7ul).

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm

Comment: asher not in this way I am asking for multiple rows not for column

Comment: I guess I don't understand this part 'but for singly email to send not for multiple email'.  I guess just change the range you are using, or condense it.  I'm not totally sure what you are talking about.